# C++ function suspend with handle to resume

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write some component code that can run in two environments

1. inside a discrete event simulator
2. on its own as an executable, with high performance

*without* having different source code inside the component itself.

In 1. there will be a queue holding callable objects where the head is continuously removed and called. The callable may add more callables to the queue.

I have a problem where inside a component callable I may have something like the following

```
callable(){
  useful_result = external_function()
}
```

where external_function can differ between the two environments (dependency injected)

In environment 2. external_function may be something like

```
external_function2(){
  //do work
  return result
}
```

Which is great and everything works fine. However the behavior I want to mimic is to replace this external_function2 with external_function1, which makes use of the queue. For example (in pseudocode)

```
external_function1(){
   //do some things
   pause! queue.push_back(resume_here) // pause and resume_here resumes here when called!
   //do more things
   return result
}
```

where resume here is some kind of magical callable which when popped off the queue will resume the function from //do more things.

Is this kind of functionality possible in C++?

I apologise if I have missed something bleedingly obvious.

Thank you.

Ps. in Javascript I could something like

```
exeternal_function1(){
   //do some things
   await new Promise((resolve,reject),()=>{
       queue.push(()=>{resolve()});
     });
   //do more things
   return result
}
```

Comment: there is std::promise and related classes, ::std::async (and even coroutines in c++ 20) but most likely you don't really need them